# Lipschitz constant of L2 difference

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

What is the Lipschitz constant of $$f(A)=||Ax||_2-||Ay||_2?$$

In particular, is it $||x-y||_2$, i.e. is it true that given $A,B,x,y$, the following inequality holds:
$$|f(A)-f(B)|\leq ||x-y||_2 ||A-B||_F$$
where $||\cdot||_F$ is the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 0):

I think the constant is $\|x\|_2+\|y\|_2$ as the best I can get is the following:
$$\begin{aligned}
|f(A)-f(B)| & \leqslant \left|\|Ax\|_2-\|Bx\|_2+\|By\|_2-\|Ay\|_2\right|\\
& \leqslant \|(A-B)x\|_2+\|(B-A)y\|_2\\
& \leqslant \|A-B\|_F(\|x\|_2+\|y\|_2)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks I agree with this. But it doesn't do what I need. I would be curious if what I claim is not correct.

Comment: I tried to find a counterexample but I was unable to. I just don't see how to prove the stronger statement, I'm sorry.